# NoReverseMatch at /en/dashboard/server-request/

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-url-reverse

Reverse for 'edit_server_request' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['en/dashboard/edit-server-request/int:pk']
the edit and delete button on the template below raises the error:

```
            <td>
              <a class="edit-button" href="{% url 'dashboard:edit_server_request' user.server_user.pk %}">{% trans 'Edit' %}</a>
              <a class="delete-button" href="{% url 'dashboard:delete_server_request' user.server_user.pk %}">{% trans 'Delete' %}</a>
            </td>
```

`views.py`

```
def edit_server_request(request, pk):
    server_request = get_object_or_404(ServerRequest, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ServerRequestForm(request.POST, instance=server_request)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('server_request_list')
    else:
        form = ServerRequestForm(instance=server_request)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/school/edit_server_request.html', context)

def delete_server_request(request, pk):
    server_request = get_object_or_404(ServerRequest, pk=pk)
    server_request.delete()
    return redirect('server_request_list')
```

`urls.py`

```
    url(r'edit-server-request/<int:pk>', school_views.edit_server_request, name='edit_server_request'),
    url(r'delete-server-request/<int:pk>', school_views.delete_server_request, name='delete_server_request')
```

edit and delete url raises the error

Comment: please post the user model for user.server_user.pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/) with [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/). If you are using Django >=2, than update the urls like this:

```
path('edit-server-request/<int:pk>', school_views.edit_server_request, name='edit_server_request'),
path('delete-server-request/<int:pk>', school_views.delete_server_request, name='delete_server_request')
```

Else you need to change the regex inside `url()` like this:

```
url(r'edit-server-request/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', school_views.edit_server_request, name='edit_server_request'),
url(r'delete-server-request/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', school_views.delete_server_request, name='delete_server_request')
```